# Override plugin generated URL with custom URL for specific page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, seo, title

I am using `SEO ULTIMATE PLUGIN` for generating dynamic title tags for each page, but for one specific page I need to show my custom title and dont't want to generate it via `plugin`.

I have disabled the pluggin for specific page but it is restricting `keywords` & `description` only not title

**Code1**

```
function hide_seo_meta_from_detail_page()
{
remove_action('wp_head', array($GLOBALS['seo_ultimate'], 'template_head'), 1);
}
hide_seo_meta_from_detail_page();
```

Also I tried `add_filter` but still coming from `plugin`
**Code2**

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'set_page_title' );
 function set_page_title( $orig_title ) {
   $title = 'My custom Title';
   return $title;
 }
```

Thanks